# Hide/Show Windows Forms panel in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, panel

I try to show/hide panels in C#, but when I clicked on button1 I wanted to see panel1 but panel2 appeared. 
And when I cliked on button2, panel2 dissappeared. 
But when I cliked first on button2, panel2 didn't appear.
I don't know what is wrong with my code but here it is:

```
public Form3()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    bool show1;
    bool show2;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(show1)
        {
            panel1.Visible = false;
            show1 = false;
        }
        else
        {
            panel1.Visible = true;
            show1 = true;
        }
        Application.DoEvents();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!show2)
        {
            panel2.Visible = true;
            show2 = true;
        }
        else
        {
            panel2.Visible = false;
            show2 = false;
        }
        Application.DoEvents();
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately your code is not complete and the problem cannot be reproduced using just what you have. Perhaps you have your events wired up backwards though?

Comment: panel2.Visible = !panel2.Visible and panel1.Visible = !panel1.Visible

Comment: You can remove the `Application.DoEvents`. First: Its use is discouraged (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181777/use-of-application-doevents), second: Control goes back to UI thread right after the `Click` method exits anyway, so the update will be done right away.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Don't* use flags, because your button behavior will be determined by the states of the flags.

Best is to code it the way you want. If you want each `Button` to make the corresponding panel visible while other panel invisible:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     panel1.Visible = true;
     panel2.Visible = false;
     //Application.DoEvents();
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     panel2.Visible = true;
     panel1.Visible = false;
     //Application.DoEvents();
}
```

Or, if you want each button to control the visibility of each panel independently, do this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     panel1.Visible = !panel1.Visible;
     //Application.DoEvents();
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     panel2.Visible = !panel2.Visible;
     //Application.DoEvents();
}
```

Lastly, the `Application.DoEvents()` can be removed (credit to [Thorsten Dittmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/117362/thorsten-dittmar)) as the control will immediately back to UI thread after the `Click` method finishes anyway. Read his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35741177/hide-show-panel-in-c-sharp/35741235#comment59156071_35741177) and the referred [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181777/use-of-application-doevents).

Comment: I try to use this code, but when I start the programme appeared panel2 (I try to make to appeared a blank panel). When I clicked on button1 appeared panel1, but when I clicked on button2, panel2 didn't appeared.

Comment: @MariaD that is pretty strange considering the command is very clear, to set the panel2.Visible = true. First, u can debug if the line is really executed when u click the button. Next, is to confirm that ur panel name is corrrct. Other than that, u may require to use VS debugger to check line by line.

Comment: I review my Form Design and I saw there another blank panel what name was panel2 and in this case my panel2 don't appeared when I clicked on button2, but now is working and thanks for help.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use global variable like `show1` and `show2`
You can do like this instead.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    panel1.Visible = !panel1.Visible; 
    Application.DoEvents();
}
```

Comment: There's no need to use `Application.DoEvents()` here, as the method will be exited anyway. While the use of `Application.DoEvents()` is considered questionable anyway, there's no need for it here.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar: I'm not sure why `op` wants to call `Application.DoEvents()`, but I leave it there anyway in case he needs it.

Comment: Ah, I didn't read that in the original question. Going to comment there, too.

Comment: I try to do this, but panels didn't appear.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use variables and condition. 
Just add `panel1.Visible = false; or panel1.Visible = true;` on button click

Answer (score 0):

You may find the solution but I just want to recommend you to use `SuspendLayout()` and `ResumeLayout()` for performance improvement while changing control states

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     this.SuspendLayout();
     panel1.Visible = true;
     panel2.Visible = false;
     this.ResumeLayout();
     //Application.DoEvents();
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     this.SuspendLayout();
     panel2.Visible = true;
     panel1.Visible = false;
     this.ResumeLayout();
     //Application.DoEvents();
}
```

Comment: I try, but is not working.