# Hide panel in usercontrol when button on main form clicked

Tags: c#

I want to hide panel in `UserControl` when button clicked in my main form I saw these codes:

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    if(ButtonClick != null)
        ButtonClick(this, e);
}

obj.ButtonClick += (Sender, e) => 
{
    splitContainer1.Panel2.Controls.Add(obj2);
};
```

but I don't know how to use it for my project I think it has to be Reverse in project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    if(ButtonClick != null)
        ButtonClick(this, e);
}

obj.ButtonClick += (Sender, e) => 
{
    splitContainer1.Panel2.Visible = false;
};
```

Also check this question for more information: [Hide/Show Windows Forms panel in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35741177/hide-show-windows-forms-panel-in-c-sharp)